# Echo Variable Within While Loop | Except Last

Tags: php

I am trying to echo a divider within a while loop after every item except the last item. Currently I have the divider after each item.

I've found a few solutions involving mysql rows and counters but so far nothing that relates to my situation.

I am using the following code (note, this does not include an attempted solution but rather my starting point.):

```
    <?php if( have_rows('testimonials') ): ?>

    <div class="testimonials col-md-4">
        <h2>What People are Saying</h2>
        <?php while( have_rows('testimonials') ): the_row(); 

            // vars
            $image = get_sub_field('image');
            $quote = get_sub_field('quote');
            $name = get_sub_field('name');
            $divider = "<div class=\"dots full\"></div>";

            ?>

                <div class="media">
                  <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                    <?php echo '<img src="'.$image['url'].'" alt="'.$image['alt'].'" class="img-circle" style="max-width: 70px;">'; ?>
                  </a>
                  <div class="media-body">
                    <div class="quote">
                        <?php echo $quote; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="source">
                        <span><?php echo $name; ?></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <?php echo $divider; ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt here. You just echo `$divider` always. SO is not a magical solution generator.

Comment: or maybe you can echo divider always, except the first time. It's easier with a flag.

Comment: There isn't an attempt because all the solutions didn't work. So I removed them in order to keep the starting point clean.

I'm looking more for some direction on where to start.

Comment: Have you thought about echoing the divider before every `div.media`, except for the first item? That's equivalent, and you can do that with a simple counter variable. Give it a try, make an attempt. Stackoverflow doesn't do your work for you...

Comment: to be able to NOT print the last divider, you'd have to know IN ADVANCE what the last item is, or how many in total you'll be printing.

Comment: I think @Frog's solution is a good one if you really want to echo it. But I think CSS would be a more elegant solution for this.

Comment: @Frog, Thanks that worked. I added the divider before and used a counter to determine if it was the first item. If so, then I did not echo the divider.

As a note, I am not coming to the community for an answer or for you to do my work, rather I am asking for the insight.

I spent a couple hours not realizing the obvious. And sometimes it's easier to get some help.

Comment: @SmashBrando: Great that you figured it out! I'm glad my hint pointed you in the right direction. Maybe it's a good idea to accept your own answer?

Comment: @Frog, 17 hours until it unlocks and allows me to accept it.

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed @Frogs advice and added the divider before each item and then used a counter to rule out the first item.

```
<?php if( have_rows('testimonials') ): ?>
    <?php $test_count = 0; ?>
    <div class="testimonials col-md-4">
        <h2>What People are Saying</h2>
        <?php while( have_rows('testimonials') ): the_row(); 

            // vars
            $image = get_sub_field('image');
            $quote = get_sub_field('quote');
            $name = get_sub_field('name');
            $divider = "<div class=\"dots full\"></div>";

            if ($test_count !== 0) { 
                    echo $divider; 
                } 

            $test_count++;
            ?>

                <div class="media">
                  <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                    <?php echo '<img src="'.$image['url'].'" alt="'.$image['alt'].'" class="img-circle" style="max-width: 70px;">'; ?>
                  </a>
                  <div class="media-body">
                    <div class="quote">
                        <?php echo $quote; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="source">
                        <span><?php echo $name; ?></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>



        <?php endwhile; ?>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```